# Intsall mt5 package

Tags: python

I want to install the MetaTrader5 module in PyCharm, but I don't know how. I tried using `pip install MetaTrader5`, but it's says

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5
```

Comment: Make sure your Python version is supported - https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/

Answer (score 1):

Which SO are you using? Are you using Ubuntu? If yes, then sadly MetaTrader5 currently doesn't support Ubuntu, it is only avaliable on Windows SO.

If you're using windows, then check your python's version. It requires a python 64bit version of 3.7 or higher.

Check more detail info [here](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5)

Comment: I'm using Mac not windows and I don't know what you mean by SO and Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I meant OS (operative system, like windows, IOS...). Ubuntu is one of them.
As far as I know, MetaTrader5 library for python is only available on Windows only, MacOS is not supported.

Comment: Is there no way to get it on Mac?

Comment: I believe that there is no way, as it looks like the package was developed only for windows. See this previous post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507776/trying-to-install-metatrader5-with-python3-on-a-mac

Comment: What if I run windows 10 on my Mac. Would it work?

Comment: I guess then it would work, yes